# Prove Big-Theta Problem

Tags: algorithms

How do I prove that (n+5)^100 = big-theta(n^100)?

I know that the highest degree is 100 and it equals to the degree of n on the right, which proves that (n+5)^100 = big-theta(n^100).

I was just wondering if there is another way to prove this with work instead of just this theorem.

Comment: One can use the fact that for $n>5$ we have $(n+5)^{100}<(2n)^{100}=2^{100}n^{100}$.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).